# Find the numerical value of the norm of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

[Here's the first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYLkG.jpg)

[Here's the second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3NNH.jpg)

$Au\cdot v = u\cdot A^{T}\cdot v$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: What is A ?  It seems that  A  is a matrix, then to find the norm of  $u$ you should apply the definition of the given norm, which is  in your case  $||u||= \sqrt{u.A.u}$.

Comment: Instead of linking to pictures of the problem, please take the time to enter them into your post. You’re asking us to spend our time helping you; it’s only fair that you spend some of your time, too. As well, images of questions are not searchable, so your question does no one else any good.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  it seems that there are some missing hypotheses on the matrix $A$; perhaps these hypotheses are written in previous parts of the problem? You should make this clear!

However, for (c1) note that

$$\|e_1\| = \sqrt{e_1 \cdot A e_1} = \sqrt{a_{11}},$$

where $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1,2}.$ To see why this is true try writing down the calculations by hand, since it only requires $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication.

Now you can think about (c2) and determine whether or not this new norm agrees with the standard norm!